why in auto-correlation function of random process, the expectation of product of two random variables gives the correlation between them
Why in auto-correlation function of random process, the expectation of product of two random variables gives the correlation between them
I understand that the pearson's formula will give correlation: # rₓ(t1, t2) = cov[x(t1), x(t2)] / [σₓ(t1) * σₓ(t2)];
But in many places, they define auto-correlation with the following formula: # rₓ(t1, t2) = e[x(t1).x̄(t2)];
Why the latter will give the correlation between the random process at different time points?

The autocorrelation function is defined as the expectation of the product $X(t_1)X( t_2)$, and it does not mean the value of the correlation coefficient as in Pearson correlation coefficient. That's all there is to it.

Thank you @DilipSarwate for the response.
Then why is it called autocorrelation? And if not correlation, then what does it measure?

To the best of my knowledge, the reasons for the name autocorrelation are historical: it was the term used by engineers and scientists who developed radar systems before and during World War II when a radar return ((hopefully a close replica of the transmitted pulse but with an unknown delay) from a target was "correlated" with the transmitted signal (actually doing a "cross-correlation").The location of the peak of this cross-correlation was a measure of twice the distance from the radar system to the target. After the War was over, it was too much of a mess to try correct the nomenclature.
